# the definition of the topological pressure for matrices

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, symbolic-dynamics

Let $:\Sigma \to GL(d, \mathbb{R})$ be a continuous matrix cocycle over a topologically mixing subshift of finite type $(\Sigma, T)$. We denote by $\Sigma_n$ the set of addmisible words with the length $n$. For any $n\in \mathbb{N},$ and $I \in \Sigma_n$, we define
$$\|A(I)\|:=\sup_{x\in [I]}\|A^{n}(x)\|.$$

We can also define the topological pressure for the potential $\log \|A\|$ as follows:

$$P(\log \|A\|):=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\log  \sum_{|I|=n}\|A(I)\|.$$

Is it true that $P(\log \|A\|)$ can also be defined as follows:
$$P(\log \|A\|)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\log  \sum_{|I|\leq n}\|A(I)\|?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is a consequence of the following simple exercise about exponential growth: if $a_n\geq 0$ is any sequence such that $P = \lim \frac 1n \log a_n$ exists, then $\frac 1n \log \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \to P$ as well. (Apply this with $a_n = \sum_{|I|=n} \|A(I)\|$.)

To prove the exercise, observe that $\liminf \frac 1n \log \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \geq P$ is immediate, so it is enough to prove that $\limsup \frac 1n \log \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \leq P$. To do this, observe that for every $P' > P$ there is $C>0$ such that $a_k \leq C e^{kP'}$ for all $k$, so $$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \leq \sum_{k=0}^n C e^{kP'} = C\frac{e^{(n+1)P'} - 1}{e^{P'} - 1}.$$